Vscode extension test use runTests.ts already installed extension, but in the test instance vscode, none of extension had installed
Vscode extension test use runTests.ts already installed extension, but in the test instance vscode, none of extension had installed.
Why? Or do I need to set something?
runtests.ts:
import { downloadAndUnzipVSCode, resolveCliArgsFromVSCodeExecutablePath, runTests } from '@vscode/test-electron';
import * as cp from 'child_process';
import path from 'path';

async function main() {
  try {
    const vscodeExecutablePath = await downloadAndUnzipVSCode('1.88.0');
    const [cliPath, ...args] = resolveCliArgsFromVSCodeExecutablePath(vscodeExecutablePath);

    const extensions = ['mathiasfrohlich.kotlin', 'scala-lang.scala'];
    const installExtensionsArgs = extensions.map((extension) => ['--install-extension', extension]).flat();

    cp.spawnSync(cliPath, [...args, ...installExtensionsArgs], {
      encoding: 'utf-8',
      stdio: 'inherit',
    });

    // The folder containing the Extension Manifest package.json
    // Passed to `--extensionDevelopmentPath`
    const extensionDevelopmentPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../../');

    // The path to test runner
    // Passed to --extensionTestsPath
    const extensionTestsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, `./suite/index`);

    const workspacePath = path.resolve('sampleWorkspace', 'test.code-workspace');

    await runTests({
      vscodeExecutablePath,
      extensionDevelopmentPath,
      extensionTestsPath,
      launchArgs: [workspacePath]
        .concat(['--skip-welcome'])
        .concat(['--skip-release-notes'])
        .concat(['--enable-proposed-api']),
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to run tests');
    if (error instanceof Error) {
      console.error('error message: ' + error.message);
      console.error('error name: ' + error.name);
      console.error('error stack: ' + error.stack);
    } else {
      console.error('No error object: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
    }
    process.exit(1);
  }
}

main();


Run log:
Found existing install in /data/git/ygqygq2/turbo-console-log/.vscode-test/vscode-linux-x64-1.88.0. Skipping download
Ignoring option 'extensions-dir': not supported for code.
Ignoring option 'user-data-dir': not supported for code.
正在 WSL: Ubuntu-22.04 上安装扩展…
已安装扩展 "mathiasfrohlich.kotlin" v1.7.1。使用 "--force" 选项更新到最新版本，或提供 "@<version>" 以安装特定版本，例如: "mathiasfrohlich.kotlin@1.2.3"。
已安装扩展 "scala-lang.scala" v0.5.7。使用 "--force" 选项更新到最新版本，或提供 "@<version>" 以安装特定版本，例如: "scala-lang.scala@1.2.3"。
[main 2024-04-22T10:32:05.692Z] update#setState disabled
[main 2024-04-22T10:32:05.696Z] update#ctor - updates are disabled by the environment

extentions not installed
I hope the extension is already installed in the test vscode.
